# parse UTC timestamp in PHP for only year, month, and date?

Tags: php, timestamp, utc

what is the best way to take a UTC timestamp (integer) and parse it for only the year, month, and day in PHP? Thanks

Comment: By UTC timestamp do you mean "Unix timestamp"?

Comment: If you're referring to a unix timestamp, you can use the date function (http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to gather the specifics. If you want to parse a formatted timestamp, please give an example.

Comment: Example: strtotime("2011-9-12 05:48:00") evaluates to be 1315806480... I want to be able to take this integer and process it into strtotime("2011-9-12") or 1315785600.

Comment: and NullUserException, No, I mean UTC timestamp. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the PHP [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

```
<?php
$timestamp = strtotime("2011-9-12 05:48:00");
$year = date('Y', $timestamp);
$month = date('m', $timestamp);
$day = date('d', $timestamp);
$newTimestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
```

Comment: Not really what I am going for.. that doesn't return the value in terms of unix timestamp.. and also, I do not need them separated.. See the example I gave in the comment to my post. Thanks

Comment: oh wow.. I didn't even read the last line of that code..  right.. I guess that is the way to do it.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class is pretty good for this kind of task

```
<?php
// for PHP5.2+ though
var_dump(date_create('2011-9-12 05:48:00')->setTime(0, 0, 0)->format('U'));
// if input is in integer already
$input = 1315806480;
var_dump(date_create("@{$input}")->setTime(0, 0, 0)->format('U'));
```

Comment: Britt's working with a Unix timestamp, so you probably want `@1315806480` in place of `2011-9-12…`.

Comment: lol, I thought the input would be somehow similar to ISO date time format

Comment: erm, I have read the comments actually, because she mentioned '2011-9-12 05:48:00' so my initial answer only considered that lol

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', *timestamp*));
?>
```

EDITED:

The **date()** function takes your timestamp and represents it in a human readable string with only the year, month, and date (i.e. "2014-07-25") and omitting the hour, minutes, and seconds.

Then the **strtotime()** function takes that human readable string and turns it back into your timestamp, effectively making the time at 00:00 on that day.